# How to count subsections and subsubsections without giving them a title

Tags: sectioning

I have a document which I want to recreate in LaTeX which has numbered subsections and subsubsections, but they have no titles, just text. How to make that in LaTeX?
Currently I'm using the tufte class (which dosn't support subsubsections, but that's another problem to be dealt with separately).

[image]

Comment: Do you have to employ numbered/empty subsections and subsubsections, or can you make do with suitably-formatted enumerated lists?

Comment: Do please also share some information about which document class you employ.

Comment: Looks somewhat similar to [sectioning - Section numbering in the left column - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100836/section-numbering-in-the-left-column). There's also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55197/how-can-i-number-paragraphs-and-sections-in-the-margin https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303779/chapter-section-etc-numbers-on-left-margin-aligned-left https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/588671/align-section-subsection-and-paragraph-number-in-left-margin-in-left-in-report but they do have section number title

Comment: Not directly answering your question, but this might be a good fit for the scrjura class, which was specifically designed to create German contracts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a list with the section number prefixed to the enumeration. Such adjustments to list parameters are provided by [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem). Here's a mockup that matches your output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
% To add a period after sectional unit numbering
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\thesection.\quad}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
\lipsum[1][1-2]

\section{Another section}
\begin{enumerate}[align=left,label*=\thesection.\arabic*,labelindent=2em]
  \item \lipsum[1][3]
  
  \item \lipsum[1][4-5]
  
  \item \lipsum[1][6]
  \begin{enumerate}[align=left,label*=.\arabic*,labelwidth=3em,leftmargin=3.5em]
    \item \lipsum[2][1-2]
    
    \item \lipsum[2][3-5]
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried not giving them a title? If not, why not?

```
% subsecprob.tex  SE 653881
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
Some text.
\subsection{First subsection}
Some text.
\subsubsection{First subsubsection}
Some text.

\section{Second section}
Some text.
\subsection{}
Some text.
\subsubsection{}
Some text.
\end{document}
```

--GOM

Comment: That's what I have now. It writes the section number on top of the section, not in s separate column left of it.

Comment: I hadn't configured that; perhaps I should have looked more closely at your question.I think that the suggestions given by the commentators to your question have an answer for you. Please check them out and if one suits you ask the commentator to provide it as an answer for general use.